# Height of the geoid in ECEF coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, wgs84, altitude, geoid

I know that the relationship of geoid height `N` and ellipsoid height `h` to orthometric height `H` is defined by `H = h - N`, but what if I have some position in [Earth-Centered-Earth-Fixed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) (ECEF) coordinates?

Specifically, I am looking to relate the height of the geoid (for some particular position on the geoid) to the earth-centered height. (Using [WGS84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) here.)

Answer (score 1):

Earth Centred Earth Fixed (ECEF) coordinates is a Cartesian system typically defined by the [EPSG](http://www.epsg.org/Portals/0/373-07-2.pdf#page=97) as:

*Z axis corresponding with the earth’s rotation axis positive northwards, the X axis through the intersection of the prime meridian and equator, and the Y axis through the intersection of the equator with longitude 90°E.*

In ECEF coordinates therefore there is no real concept of *height* in the meaning of distance above/below an equipotential surface.  It is however possible to represent an orthometric point height in an ECEF XYZ coordinate:

1. Determine the ellipsoidal height by `h=H+N` where `H` is the orthometric height and `N` is derived from the respective geoid model.  Typically the geoid model is a gridded surface that must be interpolated at the given location.
2. Convert lat/lon/h to ECEF XYZ using the equations in section 4.1.1 of the [EPSG Geomatics Guidance Note 7](http://www.epsg.org/Portals/0/373-07-2.pdf#page=97), inserting the relevant parameters for the ellipsoid used.

Inverse equations are also given in the same section, to convert from ECEF XYZ to lat/lon/h to perform the reverse procedure.  After the ellipsoidal height `h` has been determined, use the geoid height to subtract and determine orthometric height:  `H=h-N`.